# How to set CRS of many rasters in R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r

I have a set of rasters that I've had trouble reprojecting to Robinson. It fails without errors, the crs changes but the extent doesn't convert to metres and it doesn't plot properly. Sources say EPSG:32663 is deprecated.

Projecting raster with '+init=EPSG:4326' and the proj4 string together doesn't make a difference

```
r <- projectRaster(r, crs='+init=EPSG:4326 +proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs')
```

But, setting the crs this way, followed by projecting with the proj4 string does

```
crs(r) <- "+init=EPSG:4326"


r <- projectRaster(r, crs='+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs')
```

I need to do this across a list of rasters but am having trouble getting the syntax right for setting the CRS inside a function, example

```
for (i in 1:length(filenames)){
   crs(filenames[[i]]) <- "+init=EPSG:4326"
   # projectRaster(eval(as.name(filenames[[i]])),crs='+init=EPSG:4326 +proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs')
}
```

gives the following error

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘crs<-’ for signature ‘"character"’
```

This is the raster I'm working with

ftp://ftp.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/sod/mecb/crw/data/5km/v3.1/nc/v1.0/monthly/2019/ct5km_baa-max_v3.1_201901.nc

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3600, 7200, 25920000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.05, 0.05  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +init=EPSG:32663 +proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 
+lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
+ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : /Users/traveler/Desktop/Reefs/alert- 
animation/raw/ct5km_baa-max_v3.1_201607.nc 
names      : bleaching.alert.area 
z-value    : 1122811200 
zvar       : bleaching_alert_area
```

Comment: Why can't you read the raster in and use projectRaster without assign? What goes wrong with the code you have? Why have you pointed us to one raster when your problem seems to be with several rasters? Have you got several like this? Like that in what way?

Comment: If this file *really* was in epsg:32663 then its units, and hence its *extent* should be in *metres* not degrees. When you project it to Robinson and it seems to fail its because it thinks its a 360 metre x 180 metre piece of the earth centred on (0,0), not a full global map. So whoever wrote this has lost some important data somewhere. If it is epsg:4326 then try overlaying a known good epsg:4326 vector map and check the alignment.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. If I try to change the CRS in the function I get "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘crs<-’ for signature ‘"character"’ and if I try to reproject I get no error, but no result either.

Here is the rest of the data (monthly files) ftp://ftp.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/sod/mecb/crw/data/5km/v3.1/nc/v1.0/monthly/2019/

Comment: That error is because you are trying to set the crs on the *filename* - read the file into a raster object then override the incorrect 32663 CRS with what you think is the correct one (4326, but *check* that).

Comment: filenames is a list of my rasters after being read in, I'm passing them to the crs() function - are there other ways to override it?

Comment: No its not. Read the error. `unable to find an inherited method for function ‘crs<-’ for signature ‘"character"` - that `signature "character"` is telling you that `filenames[[i]]` at that point *is character* - ie most likely its the filename and *not* the raster after reading in. Your question nowhere shows what `filenames` is, or shows a raster being read from `filenames`.

Comment: Sorry I'll include that next time. I'd thought the problem was elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
readandproject = function(filenames){
 lapply(filenames, function(filename){
   r = raster(filename)
   crs(r) = "+init=epsg:4326" # fix broken CRS
   r = projectRaster(r, crs="+proj=robin +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
   return(r)
   }
)
}
```

Then `prasters = readandproject(c("file1.nc","file2.nc"))` should return a list of two projected rasters from the filenames. `plot(prasters[[1]])` to see the first one.

Also, I loaded one of the rasters into QGIS and overrode the CRS to WGS84 (epsg:4326) and compared it with OpenStreetMap's base layer, and the correlation looked pretty good up to the resolution of the raster.

Comment: This is elegant - oddly spTransform gives an "unable to find an inherited method for function" error but using projectRaster here enables it to run. I have a country borders shapefile that I have reprojected and added to the plot and it matches up nicely -  is this enough to be confident that it is 4326? (I really appreciate your help, I'd still be stuck right now!)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was ad-libbing. projectRaster it should be I'll edit.